# Do docker images have the same root password?

Tags: docker

If two persons are pulling the same docker image (let's say Debian:10.4), they will obtain the same "files" (layers) from the docker repo.

So, from what I understand, launching a docker image is not exactly like a fresh install, it is more like a preinstalled OS. So I guess the two docker images debian:10.4 launched in two separate hosts should be as equivalent as possible to avoid difference in the behaviour from a host to another.

Considering this, I am asking myself if the root's password is always the same on every debian:10.4 images.

I don't know if we know the root's password of this image or only the hash. But if someone could find a preimage of this hash, he would be able to log in in every SSH server based on a debian:10.4 ?

Or is there a minimal randomness applied at the start of a instance docker to ensure the dispersion of some security constant (root password, id_rsa key, ...) ?

Comment: I guess the root password is [never set](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/237#issuecomment-268691218)

Comment: You could easily answer this question by checking `/etc/shadow` on one or more of your containers.

Comment: Yeah I did it, and you're right: on ubuntu and debian, the password is not set. So I'm asking myself if a malicious one could be interested by publishing a image with an hardcoded root password. If the container will later expose some service to Internet (where root can authenticate), it could act as a backdoor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers don't usually let you log in as root with any password. Usually, the only way to get in is to `docker exec` from the host. There is no hash to find a preimage of.

Comment: Yes you seems to be right. Could it be interesting for a malicious person to create a docker image, let's say a mysql caontainer, with a secret admin for whom he knows the password. So he will be able to connect on every instance of this docker available from Internet (ok I know there should not be so many internet face mysql services)

Comment: @Sibwara No, that wouldn't make any sense to do. Docker containers generally don't have SSH running or exposed whether or not they're Internet-facing. Also, it would be easier to just put the malicious payload in the container.